# JQuery change all href title attributes

Tags: jquery, loops, attributes

I have been trying to get all of the links that exist, and change their title attributes if their title attribute contains 'Permalink to '. So far I have this small piece of code to remove all of the links title attributes, but I haven't been able to get any code working to detect if 'Permalink to ' exists in the title attribute and if so remove it from the title.
Any ideas, help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

//gets all links and removes 'Permalink to ' from title attribute if exists
var l = $('a');

//removes title attribute from all links
l.removeAttr('title');

});
```

Here is a JSfiddle I have working @ http://jsfiddle.net/M5F8P/1/

Comment: i think the answers not correct implemented to the op's question.He wants to EDIT the attribute text, not remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a wild card on your selector to look for all of the a tags whose title contains 'Permanent':

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('a[title*="Permalink"]').removeAttr('title'); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
l.each(function(){
  var $me = $(this);
  $me.attr('title', $me.attr('title').replace('Permalink to', '');
});
```

Comment: You were the closest, and it took me working with your code along with a little research. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "a" ).each(function( index ) {
       $(this).removeAttr('title');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code changes title attribute to 'new title' in every link element, which title contains 'Permalink to'. Just replace 'new title' with properly changed title.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if (/Permalink to/.test($this.attr('title'))) {
            // replace title attribute with new/changed value
            $this.attr('title', 'new title');
        };
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdn8k/4/)

`/Permalink to/` is [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), you can tune it for your needs. For example, `/^Permalink to /` will match only titles *starting* with "Permalink to ", and `/Permalink to/i` will be case-insensitive.